# Disable adding annotations to mapView while animating its frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview

I am animating the frame of my mapView with a UIView animation:

```
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
           self.mapView.frame = frame;
        } completion:nil];
}
```

While expanding the mapView with the above I see that mapView is adding misplaced annotations until the animation is over. When the animation is finished the misplaced annotations disappears.

The calls are as follows when I expand the map:

1. animateWithDuration begin
2. mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated
3. mapView:didAddAnnotationViews
4. mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated
5. animateWithDuration complete

No problem when I minimise the map probably because the mapView:didAddAnnotationViews isn't called.

Can I somehow disable mapviews regionWillChange while animating?

Before animation:

[image: before]

Halfway in the animation. Seeing a lot of missplaced annotations.

[image: middle]

Animation is done. All missplaced annotations is gone.

[image: after]

Comment: Are you adding/removing annotations in the regionWill/DidChangeAnimated delegate methods?  If so, try setting a boolean flag to YES before starting the animation and in the delegate methods, don't do anything if the flag is YES.  Set the flag to NO when animation is done.

Comment: No, tested with a stripped project where I only adding annotations once in viewDidLoad and then animating the map up and down. 
So I don't use any delegate method to mapView for this to happen.

Comment: How about hiding the annotations while animating ? and then show the annotations?

Comment: How about returning nil in mapView:viewForAnnotation till the animation block is over? (I am assuming that it will be called as you state that annotations are being added) That way after your animation has completed you can return the annotation view which will be placed on your mapView.

Comment: add annotation after animation is completed .

Comment: @iphonic I tested that and it worked great.

Comment: @Vijayts Can I really return nil in mapView:viewForAnnotation without exception? Anyway I think I'm better of hiding them for now, thanks

Comment: @Toydor Looks like it will not return an exception. But it might actually use the system default map pin to return as the view. So I think the approach that you have taken currently by hiding them is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a temporary solution I can suggest you to do following:
1. Make a UIImageView with screenShot of your mapView before changing it's frame
2. Add that imageView as subView to your parent view and hide your mapView.
3. animate both: imageView and mapView with changing it's frames.
4. In completion block of animation unhide your mapView and remove imageView.

Something like this:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *) view
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    }
    [view.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}

- (void)foo
{
    UIImageView *mapScreenShotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self imageFromView:self.mapView]];
    mapScreenShotView.frame = self.mapView.frame;
    [self.mapView.superview addSubview:mapScreenShotView];
    self.mapView.hidden = YES;

    CGRect frame = self.mapView.frame;
    frame.origin = ...
    frame.size   = ...
    // here no more need to animate mapView, because currently its hidden. So we will change it's frame in outside of animation block.
    self.mapView.frame = frame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
       mapScreenShotView.frame = frame;
    } completion:^{ 
       self.mapView.hidden = NO;
       [mapScreenShotView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

Use this temporary solution until you find a right way to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried another temporary solution and it seems to work pretty well. 
It's about hiding all annotations that mapView is adding during animation.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    ...

    if (self.isAnimating) {
        [annotationView hideForDurationOfSeconds:0.25f];
    }

    ...

}
```

In annotationView:

```
- (void)hideForDurationOfSeconds:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    self.hidden = YES;
    [self performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:NO afterDelay:duration];
}
```